# Error: As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address

Tags: stripe-payments, react-fullstack

I am doing an Udemy course on Full Stack React(React, Redux, MongoDB, Node) by Stephen Grider. I have run into a problem while adding Stripe checkout for payment processing.

THE PROBLEM: After I click on the "Add Credits" button, the credit card form shows up. I enter the details and submit the details. Stripe sends me a token and I send that token to 'api/stripe' route, where I finalise the charge, add 5 credits to the user model and return that updated user document to the frontend. However, I am not able to get the user back. There is an error that says: Error: As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address. I have attached a picture of the complete error message.

How can I fix the error? Note that I am using react-stripe-checkout package at the frontend and the stripe package at the backend and Redux Toolkit for state management. All the necessary code samples are as below.

```
Payments.js
import React from "react";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { handleToken } from "./tokenSlice";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const Payments = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <StripeCheckout
      name="Emaily"
      description="$5 for 5 email credits"
      amount={500}
      token={(token) => dispatch(handleToken(token))}
      stripeKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}
    >
      <Button variant="outline-warning">Add Credits</Button>
    </StripeCheckout>
  );
};

export default Payments;
```

```
billingRoutes.js
const express = require("express");
const keys = require("../config/keys");
const stripe = require("stripe")(keys.stripeSecretKey);

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 500,
    currency: "usd",
    description: "$5 for 5 credits",
    source: req.body.id,
  });
  req.user.credits += 5;
  const user = await req.user.save();
  res.send(user);
});

module.exports = router;
```

```
tokenSlice.js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
  status: "idle",
};

export const handleToken = createAsyncThunk(
  "token/handleToken",
  async (token) => {
    const { data } = await axios.post("/api/stripe", token);
    return data;
  }
);

const tokenSlice = createSlice({
  name: "token",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [handleToken.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    },
    [handleToken.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "succeeded";
      state.userInfo = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export default tokenSlice.reducer;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change currency to inr.

non-inr transaction should be in usd(Dollars) and inr transaction should be in inr(Indian Rupees).

Comment: Hello Varun Bardwaj, 

Thank you for deciding to become a new contributor!  As a new contributor, it will be helpful if you take a moment to review [Stack Overflows guidelines on how to provide a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Other community members may find this question later and providing additional details and context to your answer can help other's resolve their issues quicker. Consider adding links to source documentation and references to improve your answer quality.

Thank you for contributing and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing all the required information to Stripe. Currently your charges object passed to Stripe includes amount, currency and description, but you also need to provide customer`s name and billing address as per Stripe requirements for India export charges, details here:

[https://support.stripe.com/questions/requirements-for-india-export-charges#:~:text=Charge%20must%20be%20presented%20in,with%20cards%20issued%20outside%20India](https://support.stripe.com/questions/requirements-for-india-export-charges#:%7E:text=Charge%20must%20be%20presented%20in,with%20cards%20issued%20outside%20India)

Comment: I have gone through the Stripe documentation but I don't know how to implement that in code.